# How to connect heatmap with histogram?

Tags: r, shiny, histogram, heatmap

Let's consider my heatmap shiny code :

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)

#Data 

start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2016-10-01")
#Apple stock 
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
apple <- AAPL$AAPL.Close
#Gold
getSymbols('GOLD', src = 'yahoo', from = start, to = end)
gold <- GOLD$GOLD.Close
#S&P
getSymbols('^GSPC', src = 'yahoo', from = start, to = end)
sp <- as.numeric(`GSPC`[,4])
#Microsoft
getSymbols('MSFT', src = 'yahoo', from = start, to = end) 
msft <- MSFT$MSFT.Close

stock.frame <- data.frame(apple, gold, msft, sp)
colnames(stock.frame) <- c('apple', 'gold', 'msft', 'sp')


cmat <- cor(stock.frame)
plot_ly(z = cmat, type = "heatmap")
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        plotlyOutput("heatmap", width = "100%", height="600px")
    )
)

## server.R
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$heatmap <- renderPlotly({plot_ly(x = colnames(stock.frame), y = colnames(stock.frame), z = cmat, type = "heatmap") %>%
            layout(
                xaxis = list(title=colnames(stock.frame)),
                yaxis = list(title="ts")
            )
        
        })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

And my histogram :

**UI**

```
library(shiny) # load the shiny package

# Define UI for application
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    
    # Header or title Panel 
    titlePanel(h4('Demostration of the renderPlot() - A Histogram with stock dataset', align = "center")),
    
    # Sidebar panel
    sidebarPanel(
        
        
        
        selectInput("var", label = "1. Select the quantitative Variable", 
                    choices = c("Apple" = 1, "Gold" = 2, "S&P" = 3, "BTC"=4),
                    selected = 3), 
        
        
        sliderInput("bin", "2. Select the number of histogram BINs by using the slider below", min=5, max=50, value=15),
        
        radioButtons("colour", label = "3. Select the color of histogram",
                     choices = c("Green", "Red",
                                 "Yellow"), selected = "Green")
    ),
    
    # Main Panel
    mainPanel(
        textOutput("text1"),
        textOutput("text2"),
        textOutput("text3"),
        plotOutput("myhist")
        
    )
    
)
)
```

**Sever**

```
library(shiny) # Load shiny package


start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2016-10-01")
#Apple stock 
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
apple <- AAPL$AAPL.Close
#Gold
getSymbols('GOLD', src = 'yahoo', from = start, to = end)
gold <- GOLD$GOLD.Close
#S&P500 
getSymbols('^GSPC', src = 'yahoo', from = start, to = end)
sp <- as.numeric(`GSPC`[,4])
#Microsoft
getSymbols('MSFT', src = 'yahoo', from = start, to = end) 
msft <- MSFT$MSFT.Close

stock.frame <- data.frame(apple, gold, msft, sp)
colnames(stock.frame) <- c('apple', 'gold', 'msft', 'sp')


shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    output$myhist <- renderPlot({
      colm <- as.numeric(input$var)
      hist(stock.frame[, colm], col = input$colour, xlim = c(min(stock.frame[, colm]), max(stock.frame[, colm])), main = "Histogram of stock dataset", breaks = seq(min(stock.frame[, colm]), max(stock.frame[, colm]), l = input$bin + 1), xlab = names(stock.frame[colm]))
    })
  }
)
```

What I want to have is a special list in which I can choose if I want to have heatmap or histogram. So speaking as simply as possible I want possibility to switch between heatmap or histogram in one app (because now I have two seperate apps). Do you any idea how it can be performed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use `conditionalPanel` as shown below.

```
library(shiny) 
library(quantmod)

start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2016-10-01")
#Apple stock 
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
apple <- AAPL$AAPL.Close
#Gold
getSymbols('GOLD', src = 'yahoo', from = start, to = end)
gold <- GOLD$GOLD.Close
#S&P500 
getSymbols('^GSPC', src = 'yahoo', from = start, to = end)
sp <- as.numeric(`GSPC`[,4])
#Microsoft
getSymbols('MSFT', src = 'yahoo', from = start, to = end) 
msft <- MSFT$MSFT.Close

stock.frame <- data.frame(apple, gold, msft, sp)
colnames(stock.frame) <- c('apple', 'gold', 'msft', 'sp')
cmat <- cor(stock.frame)
### plot_ly(z = cmat, type = "heatmap")

### Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Header or title Panel 
  titlePanel(h4('Demostration of the renderPlot() - A Histogram with stock dataset', align = "center")),
  
  # Sidebar panel
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("var", label = "1. Select the quantitative Variable", 
                choices = c("Apple" = 1, "Gold" = 2, "S&P" = 3, "BTC"=4),
                selected = 3), 
    sliderInput("bin", "2. Select the number of histogram BINs by using the slider below", min=5, max=50, value=15),
    radioButtons("graphtype", label = "Select Type of Graph",
                 choices = c("Heatmap", "Histogram"), selected = "Heatmap"),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.graphtype == 'Histogram' ", 
      radioButtons("colour", label = "3. Select the color of histogram",
                   choices = c("Green", "Red", "Yellow"), selected = "Green")
    )
    
  ),
  
  # Main Panel
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("text1"),
    textOutput("text2"),
    textOutput("text3"),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.graphtype == 'Heatmap' ", plotlyOutput("heatmap", width = "100%", height="600px")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.graphtype == 'Histogram' ", plotOutput("myhist") 
    )
  )
  
)


server <-   function(input, output) {
    output$myhist <- renderPlot({
      colm <- as.numeric(input$var)
      hist(stock.frame[, colm], col = input$colour, xlim = c(min(stock.frame[, colm]), max(stock.frame[, colm])), main = "Histogram of stock dataset", breaks = seq(min(stock.frame[, colm]), max(stock.frame[, colm]), l = input$bin + 1), xlab = names(stock.frame[colm]))
    })
    
    output$heatmap <- renderPlotly({plot_ly(x = colnames(stock.frame), y = colnames(stock.frame), z = cmat, type = "heatmap") %>%
        layout(
          xaxis = list(title=colnames(stock.frame)),
          yaxis = list(title="ts")
        )
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: It's looks very nice! However if Heatmap is choosen parameters like 

 'Select the quantitative variable', 'Select the number of histogram BINs by using the slider below' as well as 'Select the color of histogram' are meaningless (heatmap does not change over these parameters). Is there any way to not visualise them when heatmap is choosed ?

Comment: Please define the titles on the server side for each plot, to get the appropriate title.

Comment: ohh I See! So simply we have to use conditionalPanel several times! Thanks ;))